# How to correctly remove a dry verge piece

Tags: roofing, fascia

I've recently had a linear dry verge fitted over my garage, its a **Manthorpe Linear Dry Verge**.

The guttering on one side was removed whilst this work was being undertaken as I was in the process of painting.

Now that's finished, I've come back to re-install the guttering and I've noticed the dry verge was not cut to accommodate for guttering.

I simply need to cut it back (red line) but would prefer to remove this portion (Blue square) of the system so that I can accurately cut.

I removed the screw (small blue square) hoping that this portion would slide off, but id doesn't seem to. I've tried wiggling it and giving it abit of pull but I'm cautious not to snap anything as I don't know how this piece is clipped in.

Rather than wait for the roofers to come back and do this for me which could take weeks, I'd like to know how difficult it is to take this piece off so I can just do it myself.

**QUESTION**: **How do I correctly remove this piece of the dry verge?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://manthorpebuildingproducts.co.uk/contentfiles/files/MBP8249-F%20-%20GLV%20SmartVerge%20Linear%20Dry%20Verge%20System%20-%20Fitting%20Instructions%20(web).pdf.
 This link will show you how the material is fixed in place. It looks like to remove the bottom piece, you will need to remove the upper piece or pieces, first.